# Java Triangles Using Stars

Tags: java

So I'm trying to make a code where the output will look like:

```
*******
 *****
  ***
   *
```

By inputting the value of 4. So basically, 7 stars and no spaces for first line, 5 stars and 1 space in front of second line and so on.

I thought that this was correct but it isn't giving me the output that I want?

```
public static void Stars(int a)
    {
        String newStars = "";
        String stars = "", spaces = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= a; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2*a - 1; j > 0; j--)
            {
                stars += "*";
            }
            for (int k = 0; k < a; k++)
            {
                spaces += " ";
            }
            newStars = spaces + stars;
            System.out.println(newStars);
        }
    }
```

It doesn't give the right output but I don't know what's wrong with my code...

Comment: Are you asking if it gives the right output?  Don't you know?

Comment: No I was asking what is wrong with my code

Comment: 1) You should initialize `stars` and `spaces` *inside* the loop (at the beginning). --- 2) Your inner loops should probably use the value of `i`, since they need to do different number of characters depending on the line being generated.

Comment: Oh okay. The output is: seven stars for all 4 lines. I tried use the value of i but it returns an infinite loop.

Comment: Then show what you tried (edit question), otherwise how do you expect us to figure out what you did wrong? But try this: Change outer loop to start at `0` and continue while `i < a`, then change space loop to `k < i`. That way you generate the correct number of spaces.

Comment: in addition to what @Andreas said, your stars are always increasing, so every new line will have more stars than the one before, you need to rethink your logic there

Comment: @m_korena Yes, the stars aren't decreasing. The number stays the same. Do you know why? I'm a beginner at Java so I don't really understand the logic... and Andreas, I went back to square one after trying different things. I'm so sorry I've started coding for only about 2 months.

Comment: @user7112926 your stars are increasing because you're never resetting stars or spaces, `stars+= "*";` means keep whatever is in stars from previous iterations, and add "*" to it. always more, never less

Comment: @user7112926, maybe you should forget about formatting, start by writing code that will figure out the relationship between the argument `int a` on one side, and the number of spaces and stars in a line on the other side, print them out as integers, and only worry about formatting when you know you have the correct count for each.

Comment: Okay so I know I want the stars to decrease by 2 and the stars to start from 2*a - 1 so that if my input is 4, it becomes 7 stars, then 5 stars and so on. I only know how to do this through multiple methods but I want to put it all inside 1 method...

Comment: exactly, so your first line has a special case, it starts with a full count of 2*a - 1, but all other lines follow the logic of decrease by 2, the first thing you'd think of here is a conditional statement that detects your first line, and treat it differently, then focus the bulk of your logic on the lines that are governed by the same logic

Answer (score 0):

`spaces` and `stars` must be initialized inside the outer loop.

Comment: Only part of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code to get you going:

```
public static void Stars(int a) {
    int starsc = 0, spacesc = 0;
    for (int i = (2 * a - 1); i > 0; i = i - 2) {  // i - 2 decreases stars by 2
        starsc = i;
        if (i != (2 * a - 1)) { // if this is the first line, no spaces!
            spacesc = (2 * a - 1) - i;
        }
        System.out.println("stars count: " + starsc + " spaces count: " + spacesc);
    }
}
```

We're counting the number of stars and spaces that should be printed in each line, go ahead and format that ...